# Delphi, TAdoConnection, Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: delphi, azure-sql-database

I'd like to move the database for several Delphi applications from on-premise SQL Server to Azure Managed Instance. It would use Azure Active Directory Integrated authentication.

We use `TADOConnections`. I'm having trouble setting the connection string. It looks like `TADOConnection` does not support Azure Managed Instance and Azure Active Directory Integrated authentication. Is that correct?

Comment: The database configuration in Azure should have a section listing connection strings.  That and making sure you have installed software supporting it on the client should do it.   ex https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I updated that software. 

I got the connectionstring:

Server=tcp:myserverXXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";

I added this to it... Provider=MSOLEDBSQL and Database=ZZZ

I’m getting “multi-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.”

Comment: Azure includes the quotes around Active Directory Integrated. I tried removing the quotes and got the same error.

Comment: Find out what provider string it gives when you select build in the dialog and select the `Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server` provider. Here it is `Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1`.

Comment: That was it. I was selecting Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server and others. I am connected now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Version 18.3 and latter of the [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) includes the required Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL.dll). Since this traffic is going across the internet keeping this up to date would be a good practice.

Then using the connection string shown for the database on Azure as a starting point you can add `Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1` (plus a `;` separator if needed) in the ADO connection string so the above driver is used.